# HTML table staggered cell merging

Tags: html, merge, html-table, cell

## >> [JSFIDDLE demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/hBDqQ/) of the question <<

---

Starting with an HTML table like the following:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
|            |            |            |
|   (0, 0)   |   (0, 1)   |   (0, 2)   |
|            |            |            |
+------------+------------+------------+
|            |            |            |
|   (1, 0)   |   (1, 1)   |   (1, 2)   |
|            |            |            |
+------------+------------+------------+
|            |            |            |
|   (2, 0)   |   (2, 1)   |   (2, 2)   |
|            |            |            |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

I would like to make 2 staggered groups of merged cells so that it looks like the following:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
|                         |            |
|                         |   (0, 2)   |
|       Merged cell       |            |
+        Group #1         +------------+
|                         |            |
|                         |    G       |
|                         |    r       |
+------------+------------+    o  #2   +
|            |            |    u       |
|   (2, 0)   |   (2, 1)   |    p       |
|            |            |            |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

The problem I run into is when I try to make an HTML table with this layout, the middle row disappears:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
|                         |            |
|       Group #1          |   (0, 2)   |
|                         |            |
+-------------------------+------------+
|            |            |    Group   |
|   (2, 0)   |   (2, 1)   |     #2     |
|            |            |            |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

That is, the web browser (latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, and IE) absolutely refuses to allow the LOWER-RIGHT corner of Group #1 and the TOP-LEFT corner of Group #2 to be in the same row. Instead, the middle row magically disappears and forces the corners to be diagonally opposite.

HTML code:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">Group #1</td>
            <td>(0, 1)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <!-- ROW THAT MAGICALLY DISAPPEARS -->
            <td rowspan="2">G#2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>(2, 0)</td>
            <td>(2, 1)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Is there a way to fix this?

---

## >> [JSFIDDLE demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/hBDqQ/) of the question <<

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I can explain the finer details of why this happens, except that the table collapses the row since there's nothing on the row that requires a height greater than zero.

To fix it, you can just add a hidden element to the rows, which will keep the row at normal height (here done with a style tag for illustration, but you'd of course do it using a css class)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">Group #1</td>
        <td>(0, 1)</td>
        <td style="visibility:hidden;border-style:none;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!-- MAGICROW -->
        <td rowspan="2">G#2</td>
        <td style="visibility:hidden;border-style:none;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>(2, 0)</td>
        <td>(2, 1)</td>
        <td style="visibility:hidden;border-style:none;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[A JSfiddle to test with](http://jsfiddle.net/PDSAP/).

Comment: Thanks, this helps explain a bit about what's going on. It's very unfortunate that you have to add extra markup to get the table to render properly though. All the markup really seems to be there already, I feel like some sort of pure CSS solution on top of the original HTML framework *should* work...